# How to display custom post types AND regular posts separately on a shared taxonomy archive?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, templates, archives, archive-template

I've looked over numerous questions and answers on problems somewhat related to this but can't seem to find the same situation or solution.

I have a custom taxonomy that needs to have an archive page that can display both custom post types and regular posts, but not in the same section. Basically there needs to be a clear difference between the CPT-posts and regular posts.

For example, if "movie guides" is the custom taxonomy, "ben affleck" is a movie guide, and "Movies" are custom post types on:
website.com/movie-guides/ben-affleck

I would like that page to **also** have regular posts that are in the "ben affleck" movie guide taxonomy, but at the bottom of the page, in a different section for regular posts/post thumbnails. So part of the page would have Movies (posts from the CPT "Movies") with Ben Affleck, and after that would be post snippets from posts about Ben Affleck.

I've found information to just pull both types of posts on the same page together, but wasn't sure how to separate them in the template which is what I'm really looking for.

UPDATE: So far I've taken part of the theme's default category template and created taxonomy-{taxonomy_slugname}.php, which has pulled the CPTs onto the page, but now I can't figure out how to add posts since it's pulling the CPT's via "get post." My theme is Braxton, if that helps.

Comment: Good question. What have you tried so far and where's your code? Have you read this http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: how would expect this to paginate, or would all results be on a single page?

Comment: @BradDalton I have but it doesn't seem to help. Updating my question with more information on what has been done.

Comment: @Milo I hadn't gotten to that part yet. I was hoping to have the CPT's paginate in a group of 9 or so, with the regular post snippets still below them/below the pagination.

Comment: The problem you'll have with pagination is that when the main query runs out of posts, subsequent pages will 404. Your secondary query can never have more posts than the main query.

Answer (score 0):

Use a new query outside the loop like this one

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=ben affleck;post_type=post' );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while $query->have_posts() : $query->the_post();

 // Loop output goes here

endwhile; endif;
```

Comment: Please note `category_name` is **not the name** of the category, but the **slug**

Comment: Yea my bad, had to say that.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your query parameters, semicolon should be an ampersand.